# API for ERC20 token balance - EtherScan

Tags: erc-20, etherscan, balances

Is there any API for `ERC20 token` balance of an address for a particular contract?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From https://etherscan.io/apis#tokens:

> Get ERC20-Token Account Balance for TokenContractAddress 
>   `https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokenbalance&contractaddress=0x57d90b64a1a57749b0f932f1a3395792e12e7055&address=0xe04f27eb70e025b78871a2ad7eabe85e61212761&tag=latest&apikey=YourApiKeyToken`

Comment: Note that you must pay to get access to this.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg Not necessarily, it's also availalable using the Free plan.

Answer (score 1):

I found this one API which is ideal to fetch any kind of balance queries (be it ERC20 Token or ETH) on any address (be it Account or Contract).
There's only **one limitation** however, there's an API limit of 1 hit in every 2 seconds.
Check this: https://github.com/EverexIO/Ethplorer/wiki/Ethplorer-API#methods

Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Cindercloud](https://cinder.cloud/ethereum-contract-api) has an API for this. For a full historic data API, consider contacting [Arkane Network](https://arkane.network)

Answer (score 0):

The Etherscan API can do this (though you have to pay for a pro account): [Get ERC20-Token Account Balance for TokenContractAddress](https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/tokens#get-erc20-token-account-balance-for-tokencontractaddress)
.

Here's an example:

```
https://api.etherscan.io/api
   ?module=account
   &action=tokenbalance
   &contractaddress=0x57d90b64a1a57749b0f932f1a3395792e12e7055
   &address=0xe04f27eb70e025b78871a2ad7eabe85e61212761
   &tag=latest&apikey=YourApiKeyToken
```

And some more details:

| PARAMETER | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| contract address | the address of the ERC-20 contract |
| address | the wallet address for which to make the balance query |

You can sign up to get an API key [here](https://etherscan.io/apis).

Answer (score -1):

For mainnet:

`https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balance&address=YourContractOrAccountAddress&tag=latest&apikey=YourApiKeyToken`

For testnet:

`https://api-<testnet>.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balance&address=YourContractOrAccountAddress&tag=latest&apikey=YourApiKeyToken`

You can generate an API key at https://etherscan.io/myapikey.

See https://etherscan.io/apis for more details.

Comment: I believe these URLs will give ether balances, not ERC20 token balances.

Comment: It is giving Ether balance not ERC20 token balance

Comment: I think, API key is not mandatory to provide